# Azure Release pipeline, terraform task - unable to authenticate with Azure, reports error 700016

Tags: terraform-provider-azure, azure-pipelines-release-task

My Release pipeline was working very fine until I deleted app registration/Service Principal  from UI and created a new one using the below command.

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name <Name of Service Principal> --password <Password>
```

I updated the values which I got from the above in "Variable Groups" below which is linked to release pipelines

[image]

However when I get terrafor plan task which is defined as below:

```
Terraform plan -out main.plan -var "ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=$(TF_VAR_ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)" -var "ARM_CLIENT_ID=$(TF_VAR_ARM_CLIENT_ID)" -var "ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=$(TF_VAR_ARM_CLIENT_SECRET)" -var "ARM_TENANT_ID=$(TF_VAR_ARM_TENANT_ID)"
```

I get the error message below:

```
* provider.azurerm: Unable to list provider registration status, it is possible that this is due to invalid credentials or the service principal does not have permission to use the Resource Manager API, Azure error: azure.BearerAuthorizer#WithAuthorization: Failed to refresh the Token for request to https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/***/providers?api-version=2016-02-01: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: adal: Refresh request failed. Status Code = '400'. Response body: {"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"AADSTS700016: Application with identifier '***()' was not found in the directory '***'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.\r\nTrace ID: 7a1e3f3a-5171-4044-b59a-49a78d3df300\r\nCorrelation ID: f61d0e14-ecf7-45b9-bbc7-e357ddb7b1dd\r\nTimestamp: 2019-03-12 10:22:16Z","error_codes":[700016],"timestamp":"2019-03-12 10:22:16Z","trace_id":"7a1e3f3a-5171-4044-b59a-49a78d3df300","correlation_id":"f61d0e14-ecf7-45b9-bbc7-e357ddb7b1dd","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=700016"}
2019-03-12T10:22:16.4925828Z
```

Just before this task that is cmd task which executes az account login with Service Principal. In log output, I can see clearly output of az account show so why this task is not working?

Output of CMD task,

```
2019-03-12T11:58:05.4615044Z Environment variable -x not defined
2019-03-12T11:58:05.4615608Z ***
2019-03-12T11:58:05.4667686Z ***
2019-03-12T11:58:05.4668423Z ***
2019-03-12T11:58:05.4669112Z ***
2019-03-12T11:58:05.4669557Z "Subscription ID=> ***"
2019-03-12T11:58:48.5462240Z [
2019-03-12T11:58:48.5463710Z   {
2019-03-12T11:58:48.5464432Z     "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
2019-03-12T11:58:48.5464946Z     "id": "***",
2019-03-12T11:58:48.5465917Z     "isDefault": true,
2019-03-12T11:58:48.5469154Z     "name": "Visual Studio Enterprise",
2019-03-12T11:58:48.5469568Z     "state": "Enabled",
2019-03-12T11:58:48.5469843Z     "tenantId": "***",
2019-03-12T11:58:48.5470058Z     "user": {
2019-03-12T11:58:48.5470290Z       "name": "***",
2019-03-12T11:58:48.5470496Z       "type": "servicePrincipal"
2019-03-12T11:58:48.5471388Z     }
2019-03-12T11:58:48.5471648Z   }
2019-03-12T11:58:48.5471999Z ]
```

It's definition is as below:

```
echo $(TF_VAR_ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)

echo $(TF_VAR_ARM_TENANT_ID)

echo $(TF_VAR_ARM_CLIENT_SECRET)

echo $(TF_VAR_ARM_CLIENT_ID)

echo "Subscription ID=> $(TF_VAR_ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)"

az login --service-principal -u  $(TF_VAR_ARM_CLIENT_ID) -p  $(TF_VAR_ARM_CLIENT_SECRET) --tenant $(TF_VAR_ARM_TENANT_ID)

az account show
```

Before I was able to provision resource without any issue.

Comment: did you grant permissions to the service principal?

Comment: I believe az ad sp create-for-rbac --name <Name of Service Principal> --password <Password> command grants permissions? as I used the same Service principal on my VM and it could provision resources without any issue.

Comment: ah right, didnt catch that

Comment: what I do in my tasks, I just use build variables named as cf wants them to be named: `ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID`,`ARM_TENANT_ID`,etc and dont declare anything. it just works

Comment: May need a separate question. I have drill down the problem, Looks like access token is getting lost
* provider.azurerm: Error building AzureRM Client: Error populating Client ID from the Azure CLI: No Authorization Tokens were found - please re-authenticate using `az login`.

Answer (score 2):

hopefully you've already resolved this, but in case anyone else has a similar issue, this is how I resolved the same error.   If you're using a service principal to auth, you need to make sure the azurerm provider has all of the necessary values (this happens automagically with a normal azure cli login, as it sets the proper env variables for you).   The easiest way to do this is make sure your provider is setup like the below (and the appropriate values are provided for each of the variables through --var or --var-file.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version         = "=1.24.0"
  tenant_id       = "${var.tenant}"
  subscription_id = "${var.subscription}"
  client_id       = "${var.client_id}"
  client_secret   = "${var.client_secret}"
}
```